# Prevent CKEditor5 from filtering out classes

Tags: ckeditor5

CKEditor5 filters out any classes applied to HTML elements. However, I'd like to allow certain classes to be applied to `<ul>` elements (e.g. `class1`, `class2`) without CKEditor5 stripping them out.

I tried creating an HTML Purifier config (as below), but the classes I apply in Source still gets stripped out upon save.

```
{
   "HTML.Allowed": "ol[class],li"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but would simply rewriting the output in your template solve your problem? If you wanted such classes to *always* be applied then you can just do something like this in Twig:

```
{{ richText|replace({
  '<ul>': '<ul class="class1">',
  '<ol>': '<ol class="class2">',
}) }}
```

Comment: I need to be able to add different classes to each `<ul>` element, so this wouldn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The CKEditor5 plugin supports custom configuration on a per-field basis, which can include style definitions. In the [documentation](https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor#configuration), you'll see how to create a custom field config. So it sounds like you might want to add a style definition like so:

```
  style: {
    definitions: [
      {
        name: 'Class One',
        element: 'ul',
        classes: ['class-1']
      },
      {
        name: 'Class Two',
        element: 'ul',
        classes: ['class-2']
      },
    ]
  }
```

Once these are registered, they should show up in the "styles" dropdown, and be applicable when the matching tag is selected. You can also the CSS for these styles in the Custom Styles field, which controls how they are displayed in the editor.

Once these styles are registered, CKEditor shouldn't filter them out on save. The HTMLPurifier config is helpful in this case as well.